# Width of Input inside SAPUI5 FlexBox

Tags: flexbox, sapui5

Trying to extend the width of an Input inside a FlexBox container. I'd like it to be same width as parent container. This is my view.xml:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m">
    <l:VerticalLayout id="idVL" class="sapUiContentPadding" width="100%">
        <l:content>
            <Panel id="idPnl">
                <FlexBox id="idFB">
                    <Input id="idInput">...</Input>
                </FlexBox>
            </Panel>
        </l:content>
    </l:VerticalLayout>
</mvc:View>
```

Inspecting the page in the browser reveals that the parent FlexBox actually extends to the width set in VerticalLayout. However, SAPUI5 automatically creates a sub-div, which doesn't extend to the whole width, and places the input inside *that*:

```
<div id="xxxxx---view--idFB" data-sap-ui="..." class="..."> //This is the parent FlexBox, it extends to the size of VerticalLayout element.
    <div id="__data4" style="order:0;flex-grow:0;flex-shrink:1;..." class="..."> //This sub-FlexBox is created automatically, and is smaller than it's parent.
        <div id="xxxxx---view--idInput ...> //The input is placed here.
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I could be wrong but I suspect "flex-grow:0" is the culprit and I can't find a way to access this property. I tried setting it in css inside #idFB which didn't work. Also tried setting it inside some of those classes used by the sub-div (like ".sapMFlexItem"), also didn't work. Tried setting each container's width to 100%, also doesn't work. The documentation doesn't mention anything about manually setting flex properties.

How can I set flex-grow to 1, or by some other method make the input extend to the same width of VerticalLayout?

Note: I'm not 100% sold on using a FlexBox here; I just don't know of any other container I can use to place an input and button inside of, and programatically insert more of in the page, ie:

controller.js:

```
addInput: function () {
    var oInput = this.byId("idInput").clone();

    var delButton = new sap.m.Button({
        icon: "sap-icon://delete",
        press: this.deleteInput
    });

    var _oLayout = new sap.m.FlexBox({  // Some other better container?
        items: [oInput, delButton]
    });
    this.byId("idPnl").addContent(_oLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. Need to place the following inside of Input:

```
<Input>
    ...
    <layoutData>
        <FlexItemData growFactor="1"/>
    </layoutData>
</Input>
```

Comment: I was trying to insert a List inside a FlexBox and this one here saved me. Thank you a lot!